# Java generics and casting to a primitive type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am currently trying to learn how to use Generics from a book. In this chapter it says to take a piece of data T and convert it to an integer. I am trying different things in Eclipse, but none of them seem to allow this. How could you perform the following task:

```
LinkedList<T> arr = new LinkedList<T>();

Float fl = 8.74273123948;
arr.add(fl);
```

Then in another class:

```
public int findValue(Node node)
{
  T data = node.data;
  int value = Number.valueOf(data);  
  return value;
}
```

I have tried using `.valueOf()` and `(int)` among a few other things and nothing seems to satiate Java. The book insists on keeping the method generic in case floats or doubles were used instead of strings or ints.

EDIT: For other people that might have a similar question. Gleaned from all the comments to this question and the answer that was accepted:

use the .toString() on the data and then parse it as you need to whichever data type you need.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "generic constraints". e.g. `<T implements IntegerConvertible>`

Comment: Where is Node coming from? how is data defined? Is T bound?

Comment: The node isn't defined per se in this text, but it is described as "having a generic List with Node<T>". So, in my limited understanding this Node can be literally anything.

Comment: Then the only way is to use the `instanceof`-operator to check whether the generic implements `IntegerConvertible` or extends `String` or such, cast it and do according logic if yes and throw an `OperationNotSupportedException` if no.

Comment: What "task" do you mean with your first (and only) question? This is completely out of any context that might indicate what is meant by the book. These two lines `Linked ... 13");` don't make sense in this combination.

Comment: @laune Basically I'm asking how do you get an integer value, i.e. Number.intValue() or Integer.parseInt() for a generic, when generic could be a String, Integer, Float, or Double. I cannot find a method to let me *attempt* to cast a T as an integer. The task is to get an int value from T no matter what its type is, but Java will not let me cast it, parse it, or anything else.

Comment: That's because it could be something which cannot be meaningfully casted to an integer. The only guarantee you have is that T inherits from Object, from which, at best, you could retrieve a hashValue or Java object id. If you cannot define constraints, I see no alternative to working it out with conditionals such as `if (data instanceof String) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: you can even not bound it and still treat it like Object which it becomes during type erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, that is an odd book. I'll try to tell you the gist of it based on what I know.

Generics are a construct that allow you compile-time check of whether a type you are trying to use in a specific collection, method, or class is actually something that knows the functionality that is necessary for that specific thing to function.

For example, you need to use the function determined by the interface called SearchParameter in your template, but you only see the `<T>` parameter as an object. Or maybe a better example in your case would be a custom interface called `IntegerConvert` like so:

```
public interface IntegerConvert
{
    Integer returnAsInteger();
}
```

And you could have a class like this:

```
public class MyData implements IntegerConvert
{
    private String data;

    public MyData(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer returnAsInteger()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(data); //throws ParseException if it doesn't work
    }
}
```

And then you could have a List of these like this:

```
List<IntegerConvert> listOfConvertibles = new ArrayList<IntegerConvert>();
```

or if you want to go a bit more generic for the future,

```
List<? extends IntegerConvert> listOfConvertibles = new ArrayList<IntegerConvert>();
```

and then you can do

```
listOfConvertibles.add("25");
listOfConvertibles.add("40");
listOfConvertibles.add("35");
for(IntegerConvert ic : listOfConvertibles)
{
    System.out.println("" + ic.returnAsInteger());
}
```

Although that was a bit of an overcomplicated example, I guess. A simpler example would be the following:

```
public class Node<E>
{
    private E data;

    public Node(E e)
    {
        this.data = e;
    }

    public E getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(E e)
    {
        data = e;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        List<Node<Float>> listOfFloatNodes = new ArrayList<Node<Float>>();
        listOfFloatNodes.add(new Node<Float>(new Float(8.7472742f)));
        listOfFloatNodes.add(new Node<Float>(new Float(5.56842742f)));
        listOfFloatNodes.add(new Node<Float>(new Float(6.5467742f)));
        MyOtherClass moc = new MyOtherClass();
        moc.useNodeList(listOfFloatNodes);
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public <E> void useNodeList(List<Node<E>> list)
    {
         for(Node<E> node : list)
         {
             printNode(node);
         }
    }

    public <E> void printNode(Node<E> node)
    {
         node.print();
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, comment.

Comment: After reading through your code I was struck with an idea that stems from your code as well as taking some lessons from everyone that helped with this question. Thank you all.

Comment: yes this is how generics should be used. In MyOtherClass since all are instance level methods, the type parameter could be added to class itself.

Comment: Indeed, but this way you don't need to specify the type parameter at the instantiation of the class. In a specific use-case, I ran into a scenario in which the template parameters differed between the functions because there were two methods, and one of them was using an extended version of the other interface, and so it helped that the functions were parametrized but not the whole class itself.

Comment: Overall, I'm glad it helped :) Generics can be confusing, I figured it out because it was a necessity in order to merge the logic of 20 classes into one place, heheh.

Answer (score 0):

try to observe below examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test0("13");
    test0(new Integer(13));
    test1();
    System.out.println(findValue(new Node("10")));
}

private static <T> void test0(T a) {
    LinkedList<T> arr = new LinkedList<T>();
    arr.add((T) a);
    System.out.println(arr.getFirst());
}

private static <T> void test1() {
    LinkedList<T> arr = new LinkedList<T>();
    arr.add((T) new Integer(13));
    System.out.println(arr.getFirst());
}

public static <T> int findValue(Node node) {
    T data = (T) node.data;
    int value = Integer.valueOf(data.toString());
    return value;
}
```

where Node is :

```
    public class Node {

    //this should be private
        public String data;

        public Node(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    //use getter below to access private data
    public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

  }
```

all this is possible because, unchecked casts from a known type to T is allowed (of course with warnings) and compiler believes you for the casting.

Answer (score 0):

Answer not entirely on the topic albeit closely related. I had a problem and didn't find the answer. Then I found solution and thought I'd share:

I was trying to cast generic value to primitive type:

```
<TYPE> boolean equal(TYPE val, Class<?> type) {
    if (float.class == type) {            
        float val2 = (float) val; // incompatible types: TYPE cannot be converted to float
        float val3 = (float) (Object) val; // works
        ...
```

Long story short: first version doesn't work and the second does. Quite annoying.