# Creating a new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a question about creating a new array list.

If i create a new one, with

```
ArrayList <?> listtwo = new ArrayList<?>();
```

What can i put into the array? Can i put Strings and Integers in it?
Or how does this work.

I know that if you create an list like :

```
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
```

that you can only put `Strings` in it. and if u try to do something else it gives a compile exception.

Comment: you can just put string values in ArrayList<String> and if you wanna put other values ,you have to convert them into string!

Comment: I know you can in ArrayList<string> but my question is, what can i put in Arraylist<?>

Comment: `List<?>` as an interface pretty much stands for the bounds of `List<? extends Object>`. Doesn't really limit much.

Comment: I posted some information about generics here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574478/java-generics-and-casting-to-a-primitive-type/24575113#24575113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here.

(a) `new ArrayList<?>` is not a legal expression.

If you want to create a list that can hold String and Integers you need to use `ArrayList<Object>` as `Object` is the (most specific) common super-type of `String` and `Integer`:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>;
list.add('abcd'); // insert a string
list.add(1234); // insert an integer
```

The down side is that when you extract an item from this list it will be of type `Object` so you will need to downcast it:

```
String s = (String) list.get(0);
Integer n = (Integet) list.get(1);
```

(b) Regarding  the wildcard `?` symbol:

It can be used for specifying the type of a variable, as in: `ArrayList<?> list = ...`  but it cannot be used in a `new` expression. In other words, this expression is illegal: `new ArrayList<?>`.

The wildcard is useful for allowing (limited) polymorphism between lists. Specifically, if you have a List of `Integer`s and you want to treat it like a list of `Number` (which makes sense as `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`) you can use the wildcard symbol.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(100);
list2.add(200);

// This assignment is OK:
ArrayList<? extends Number> list3 = list2;   
Number n = list3.get(0); // n is now 100
```

However, the problem with list3  (or any other list with a wildcard type) is that you cannot mutate it. For instance, if you try to add an element to this list:

```
list3.add(300); // <-- This is not allowed
```

you will get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 2):

> If i create a new one, with
>
> ```
> ArrayList <?> listtwo = new ArrayList<?>();
> ```

You can't. You can't instantiate a parameterized type without bounds. Here's what the compiler will say:

```
      ArrayList <?> listtwo = new ArrayList<?>();
                                           ^
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ?
```

So the question of what you can put in it is moot.

If you didn't supply a type parameter at all:

```
ArrayList listtwo = new ArrayList();
```

...you could put anything you liked into it (including a mix of things). Primitive values will get coerced to their object equivalents (`int` => `Integer`, etc.). At that point, it's basically an `ArrayList<Object>` instance.

Comment: Thanks, i was confused about this!