# How to return a generic Collection in java

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist, set

I would like to do something like this, but it doesn't work clearly, any suggestions?

```
public HashSet<?> insert(String word, int val, HashSet<?> set) {

    if (val > 30) set.add(word);
    else set.add(val);

    return set;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to add a `String` and an `Integer` to a generic `Set`?

Comment: @Josh with that attitude you shouldn't expect to have anymore questions answered. Keppils question is valid.

Comment: `HashSet<?>` means, the type of accepted elements is unknown. Hence you cannot put anything into such a set. Btw. I can't imagine one single use case where mixing `Integer`s and `String`s in the same set is required!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do, since you're adding values to the `Set`, and you have both `Integer` and `String` as possible types (which have only `Object` as a common super class), is:

```
public HashSet<Object> insert(String word, int val, HashSet<Object> set) {    
    if (val > 30) {
        set.add(word);
    } else {
        set.add(val);
    }
    return set;
}
```

The problem here is that when you return the `Set` you **will be forced to cast** its element to some specific type (`Integer` or `String`). Possibly you'd need to investigate some time in re-designing your model and then try to work efficiently with the Generic types.

Comment: That's wrong approach, because, for example, `HashSet<String>` is not `HashSet<Object>`. But I would agree, that's strange, that we can add number and string into one set.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg and how else would you be able to add both an ``int`` and a ``String`` value to the same set? You're missing the point of the OP's question.

Comment: The "point" of OP's question is that he wants to make a generic that doesn't actually use the benefits of generic, and I'm not sure why :D

Comment: @Zhuinden, because of poor design, probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but it won't work):

```
public <T> Set<T> insert(String word, int val, Set<T> set) 
{
    if(val > 30)
    {
        set.add(word);
    }
    else 
    {
        set.add(val);
    }

    return set;
}
```

By the way, this code here that is inside the method only works with `Set<Object>` which kinda ruins the point of generics.

EDIT: Indeed, it didn't work because T would need to be bound to extend both String and Integer, which is not possible.

The way generic is meant to be used is the following:

```
public <T> Set<T> insert(T t, Set<T> set)
{
    set.add(t);
    return set;
}
```

This way, you can only put a particular type of elements into the Set, so that you don't need to cast when you retrieve them. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    insert("Hello", set);
    insert("World!", set);
    for(String string : set)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    insert(562, set); //won't compile because it allows only strings
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Hmm I'll look into it. In the meantime, here's an example on generics that I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574478/java-generics-and-casting-to-a-primitive-type?lq=1

Comment: Edited answer accordingly