# Java Generics - use of extends keyword

Tags: java, generics

I read the document on Java Generics, and it said that the java 'extends' keyword in connection with Generics means and class which implements that interface.

Based on this, i tried to create generic classes to understand this further. Here is my sample code.

Interface code:

```
package com.vipin.generics.doubtclear;

public interface DemoInterface1<T> {

    void display(T t);
}
```

Now, I created few simple classes which implements this interface:

```
package com.vipin.generics.doubtclear;

class myClass<T> implements DemoInterface1<T> {

    public myClass(T t) {

    }

    @Override
    public void display(T t) {
        System.out.println("Inside display method of myClass, object is ---> "+t);
    }
}

class myClass1<T> implements DemoInterface1<T> {

    public myClass1(T t) {

    }

    @Override
    public void display(T t) {
        System.out.println("Inside display method of myClass1, object is ---> "+t);
    }
}
```

Here is the class which has main, which tries to create objects:

```
public class DoubtClear1 {

    static <T extends DemoInterface1<T>> void myFunc(T t) {
        t.display(t);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myClass<Integer> iObj = new myClass<Integer>(1);
        myClass1<Integer> iObj1 = new myClass1<Integer>(1);
        DoubtClear1.myFunc(iObj);

    }
}
```

- In main I am creating `myClass<Integer>` and `myClass1<Integer>` objects.
- As per my understanding of 'extends' keyword when applied to Generics `myFunc()` is capable of taking any object reference which implements `DemoInterface1` interface .
- This is what i am doing in call ==> `DoubtClear1.myFunc(iObj);`

However, this is giving me compile-time error:

```
The method myFunc(T) in the type DoubtClear1 is not applicable for the arguments (myClass<Integer>)
```

This is really confusing.  I am doing what is written in the documentation on this topic and it is failing. I am not sure if my understanding of this topic is correct.

From what I feel, Generics is confusing, and it takes repeated study to really get what this is.

Any information to clear this point really appreciated.

Comment: it's because you are evaluating the condition `static <Integer extends DemoInterface1<Integer> > void myFunc(Integer t) {` which is not true, as `Integer` is not a `DemoInterface1`.

Comment: `From what I feel, Generics is confusing, and it takes repeated study to really get what this is.` Yes, it can be confusing at first but it all makes sense, you just need to work out the logic. Stick with it and you'll master it.

Comment: You should look at this example I wrote a while ago, although I'm not sure if it's the best possible explanation (I wrote it a while ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574478/java-generics-and-casting-to-a-primitive-type/24575113#24575113

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Is this statement wrong then wrt Java Generics. <T extends XYZ> --> as per the book that i referred, this means T can take any class which implements interface XYZ? I was trying to do so in my code.

Comment: Edited my post for better explanation.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: I got your point we have to pass object like myClass1<Integer> and NOT Integer. However, when we do like: myClass1<Integer> iObj1 = new myClass1<Integer>(1), isn't iObj1 of myClass1<Integer> type, and NOT Integer. This i am passing to myFunc().  Does <T> gets replaced with Integer? or with the object with which we are calling it? May be, this is the cause of confusion. Please explain. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have doubt because like this: <T extends XYZ<T>> . What does it means? It is confusing because we are still framing definition of T and also pass it some XYZ. If this is valid, then are we effectively passing:  T extends XYZ<T extends XYZ<.....>> It is sort of recursion. I am more confused than ever. I try hard to understand this, i still get doubts. The books that i refer they add more confusion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are evaluating the condition

```
static <myClass1<Integer> extends DemoInterface1<myClass1<Integer>> void myFunc(myClass1<Integer> t) {
```

Which is not true, `myClass1<Integer>` does not match `DemoInterface1<myClass1<Integer>>`, because `Integer` generic condition of `myClass1` is not `myClass1<Integer>` (because it is `Integer`).

You should instead do the following

```
static <T> void myFunc(DemoInterface1<T> interface, T t) {
    interface.display(t);
}
```

As such, the following should work

```
myClass<Integer> iObj = new myClass<Integer>(1);

myClass1<Integer> iObj1 = new myClass1<Integer>(1);

DoubtClear1.myFunc(iObj, 1);
```

EDIT: If you wanted to add a new interface that extends from `DemoInterface1` then that would change the `myFunc` parameters like so

```
static <T, N extends DemoInterface1<T>> void myFunc(N interface, T t) {
    interface.display(t);
}
```

Which I assume is originally what you wanted.

EDIT2:

The error in your code didn't happen because of this:

```
<T extends XYZ>
```

This indeed means that `T` implements or extends from `XYZ`.

The error was because you used it like this:

```
/*
    T extends from DemoInterface1, okay - this is myClass1 
       |
       |             the generic parameter of that 
       |             DemoInterface1 is bound to T, 
       |             which as mentioned, 
       |             extends from DemoInterface1 
       |             (in your case, it means this is myClass1<Integer>, NOT Integer)
       |                         |
       |                         |
       |                         |
       |                         |          here you receive a bound for T
       |                         |          where T is meant to extend from
       |                         |             DemoInterface1<T>
       |                         |          in your example, T is myClass1<Integer>, and NOT `Integer` that is the <T> of DemoInterface1<T> (myClass1<Integer>)
       |                         |              
       |                         |               |
      \|/                       \|/             \|/         */
static <T extends DemoInterface1<T>> void myFunc(T t) {
    t.display(t);
}
```

Basically, the `T` that your `display` method receives is not `Integer`, it's `myClass1`

EDIT3:

```
I got your point 
we have to pass object like myClass1<Integer> 
and NOT Integer. However, when we do like: 

myClass1<Integer> iObj1 = new myClass1<Integer>(1), 

isn't iObj1 of myClass1<Integer> type, and NOT Integer. 

This i am passing to myFunc(). 
Does <T> gets replaced with Integer? 
or with the object with which we are calling it? 
May be, this is the cause of confusion. 
Please explain. Thanks a lot!
```

Yes, you are giving `myFunc` your `iObj1` instance. As such, the `<T>` in `static <T extends DemoInterface1<T>> void myFunc(T t) {` is resolved to be `myClass1<Integer>`.

However, you are also using this as the parameter for `display` in `t.display(__)`. As a result, you are trying to give a `myClass1<Integer>` to the method of `iObj1.display(__)`, which however awaits `Integer`. Essentially, you're pretty much calling `iObj1.display(iObj1)`, and `display(T)` awaits `Integer`, not `myClass1<Integer>`.

Comment: isn't he currently evaluating `<myClass<Integer> extends DemoInterface1<myClass<Integer>>`?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is this function:

```
static <T extends DemoInterface1<T> > void myFunc(T t) {
    t.display(t);
}
```

Then you call it like such:

```
myClass<Integer> iObj = new myClass<Integer>(1);
DoubtClear1.myFunc(iObj);
```

Now, `myClass<Integer>` does not match the type `T extends DemoInterface1<T>` but the type `T extends DemoInterface1<Integer>`. So maybe you want something like this:

```
static <T extends DemoInterface1<?> > void myFunc(T t) {
    t.display(t);
}
```

That would work. (Unless I misunderstood your intentions.)

Comment: What you are doing is side stepping type erasure. It is a valid solution, but not explain why the original did not work

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I deleted my post temporarily too as such because he intends to receive the `T` parameter that is within the `DemoInterface1` to give it to the `DemoInterface1`'s `display(T)` method, as such the parameter should not be bound to `<T extends DemoInterface1>`

Comment: Exactly, because documentation of Generics says that <T extends DemoInterface1<T> > means T can be any class which IMPLEMENTS this interface. In my code these two classes implement this interface and hence should work.